# SharePoint 2010 - moving databases to new server & RBS

Tags: migration, content-database, remote-blob-storage, rbs

Our SQL cluster has some issues and techs are now building another cluster where we will have to migrate our SharePoint 2010 farm. I found technet article describing process of moving SharePoint databases to new server. But we have one RBS-enabled content database. I'd like to know if it is possible to migrate such database (migrate physical volume to new server)?

Is there any procedure which I could follow to safely migrate this content database witho no data loss?

Or maybe only solution would be to migrate BLOB storage into database file, move it in the same manner as rest of the databases and then reenable RBS on the new server, which would extract BLOB into physical volume on new server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully migrated RBS enabled database into new cluster. This article was very helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283097.aspx. It is very important to take note of the filestream provider name. Then you can detach database, and copy primary file, log file and BLOB storage folder to new server and attach.

It is also important to remember to enable FILESTREAM on all nodes of the cluster. Without it, SQL query to attach database doesn't work.