# How to do we Backup/Restore the RBS enabled Content DB in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, rbs

As a SharePoint admin, I dont have any clue on SQL Backup/Restore, however trying to implement RBS on SharePoint 2010.

Please let me know how could I handle the Backup/Restore of the RBS enabled content DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very important to take note of the filestream provider name. Then you can detach database, and copy primary file, log file and BLOB storage folder to new server and attach.

It is also important to remember to enable FILESTREAM on all nodes of the cluster. Without it, SQL query to attach database doesn't work.

[SharePoint 2010 - moving databases to new server & RBS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62995/sharepoint-2010-moving-databases-to-new-server-rbs)

[Move a FILESTREAM-Enabled Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283097.aspx)

Comment: Which means that I could follow the same procedure to backup/restore the production content dbs in case of failure/disaster? My primary concern is not to move the dbs but to restore in case of failure.

Comment: yes, If you are trying to backup the database by using SQL Backup

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to back up the DB and the file system location to where the RBS content lives. The DB holds a pointer to the file share. So if you don't back up the share, you lose all your content.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to backup&restore the mdf, ldf & blob store? and wont be using the SQL backup/restore method?