# SharePoint migration to another environment 2016 - RBS enabled Content DB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rbs

Would like to know the process or steps to migrate/setup staging environment from production for SharePoint 2016 with multiple content DB enabled with RBS.

For non-RBS DB's we followed mount and dismount content DB approach, would like to know the steps for RBS enabled DB's.

Disabling RBS / moving the data into content DB then backup restore will not be an optimal solution since the DB size is huge and cannot afford any disturbance to production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Detachment and reattachment are necessary for database migration. It is recommended that you perform migrations during low usage periods.

You can use the same Microsoft PowerShell command to migrate content to another RBS provider.

When RBS is implemented, SQL Server itself is regarded as an RBS provider.

References:

[Migrate content into or out of RBS in SharePoint Server.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/migrate-content-into-or-out-of-rbs)

[Move a FILESTREAM-Enabled Database.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/move-a-filestream-enabled-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

Another similar post: 
[SharePoint 2010 - moving databases to new server & RBS.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62995/sharepoint-2010-moving-databases-to-new-server-rbs)

Answer (score 0):

Granted I've only done two RBS migrations, but I've not been able to figure out how to migrate the RBS enabled DBs without doing the disable RBS and moving the data into the DB steps.  Either that or using the Move-SPSite command to move site collections from the RBS DB to a non-RBS DB.